How can I use a modified String in a C# switch → case statement?
I have a string I need to use, a variant of, in many places throughout my application. For example:
String myString = "The Quick Brown Fox";

string someLowerCaseString = myString.ToLower();
string someUpperCaseString = myString.ToUpper();
string someOtherNewString = myString.Replace(' ','+');

I have this String in a Constants.cs file that I reference throughout the application. I have tried two different approaches:
public const String myString = "The Quick Brown Fox";
public static readonly String myString = "The Quick Brown Fox";

However, when I try to "manipulate" the string for use in a switch → case statement, I cannot get it to work:
switch(some_value){
    case Constants.myString.ToLower():
    case Constants.myString.ToUpper():
    case Constants.myString.Replace(' ','+'):
}

I get the error:
CS0426: The type name 'myString' does not exist in the type 'Constants'
I have even tried this:
String localString = Constants.myString.ToLower();
String localString = Constants.myString.ToUpper();
String localString = Constants.myString.Replace(' ','+');
const String localString = Constants.myString.ToLower();
const String localString = Constants.myString.ToUpper();
const String localString = Constants.myString.Replace(' ','+');
switch(some_value){
    case localString:
}

And that does not work either. I get the error:
CS9135: A constant value of type 'string' is expected
I cannot use this:
switch(value.ToLower()){
    // ...
}

As sometimes I need the first letter capitalized and sometimes I need all letters upper/lowercase.
The official Microsoft C# documentation says that these modifying methods return a copy of the string, so I didn't think I was actually manipulating the String constant.

Switch statements expect constant values, you can't switch on a variable. Even if the string itself is constant, functions that you call afterwards might not be. ToLower itself isn't even constant, it can return different results based on the locale.

@ipodtouch0218 that is why I tried this: const var = Constants.myString.ToLower(), which copies the modified string into a constant.

I think you misunderstand how the const keyword works in C#. const works like a replacement: every time the compiler sees a const variable, it replaces it with the literal value. const is a compile-time feature, you can't make a new variable const at runtime. This is also why you can't do things like const string x = "abc".ToLower(); because ToLower is a runtime function. What would the value of the const be if it were instead const string x = "abc".ToUppercaseOnMondays()?

What do you actually want to do with this? Tell us about the problem that led you cook up this broken solution..

Try this:
using System;

namespace CSharpTests
{
    internal class Constants
    {
        public const String myString = "The Quick Brown Fox";
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String some_value = Constants.myString.ToLower();
            
            switch (some_value)
            {
                case string s when s == Constants.myString.ToUpper():
                    Console.WriteLine("Is upper");
                    break;
                case string s when s == Constants.myString.ToLower():
                    Console.WriteLine("Is lower");
                    break;
                case string s when s == Constants.myString.Replace(' ', '_'):
                    Console.WriteLine("Is replaced");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("None of the cases");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}


The case labels must be constants, but you can use:
if (some_value.Equals(myString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ||
    some_value.Equals(myString.Replace(' ', '+'), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
    // ...
}

Where the StringComparison could also be StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase or StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase depending on your needs.
This approach will not only work with lower or upper case but also with mixed case.

You can make the switch-statement work if you make myString a constant with all lower case characters and also add a second constant with the + signs:
const String myString = "the quick brown fox";
const String myStringPlus = "the+quick+brown+fox";

switch (some_value.ToLower()) {
    case myString:
    case myStringPlus:
        // ...
        break;
    // ...
}

I you cant make them constants, you will have to revert to if-else statements.
